# Action after a form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is there a way in which after a form is submitted you can change the value of a field?

I have a form where a `select` field is disabled, in order to post the form I enable it but immediately after I want it to be set back to disabled is `true`. This is my code:

```
    $("Form").submit(function() {
    $("#done", this).prop("disabled", false);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test it right now but try this approach:

```
$('Form').submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();                        // don't submit multiple times
    $('Form.select').prop('disabled', true);  // Enable the select
   this.submit();                             // use the native submit method
   $('Form.select').prop('disabled', false);  // Disable the select
});
```

Let me know how this works out.

OR

```
    $('Form').submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();                        // don't submit multiple times
       $('Form.select').prop('disabled', true);  // Enable the select
       $.post('action.php', $('Form').serialize());  // AJAX submit
       $('Form.select').prop('disabled', false);  // Disable the select
    });
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for response , but I get the original `missing argument` error back

Comment: hmm if you are trying to submit the form with a new request I'm afraid  that this approach won't work, are you ajax submitting the form or via request?

Comment: if you would like to add an after submit action, I would recommend using an AJAX POST submit instead of this.submit(); Check out my update above.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just sending the form once via standard from action=post. I may change server side code to check form response and decide which arguments to get.